# How to flatten the group of numbers that has the type of numpy.float64

Tags: python, numpy

There is a group number with types of <numpy.float64>

```
0.0
1.0
1.4142135623730951
2.0
```

I want to flatten them and to be in the format of

```
 [0.0,1.0,1.4142135623730951,2.0]
```

Since this type is not iterable, I cannot use a for loop.

Comment: I may be misinterpreting the question, but is this what you want? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html

Comment: If I use it, I will get [0.] [1.] [1.41421356][2.] but what I want is [0,1,1.41421356,2]

Comment: @ad79h What is type of your data? Can you test it? It could be a structured array but I'm not sure: `np.array([(0.0,), (1.0,), (1.4142), (2.0,)], dtype=[('name',  'float')])`

Comment: 'group of numbers'?  That's not a formal data structure in Python or `numpy`.  We'd like to see more precision in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use np.flatten()

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 1.4142135623730951, 2.0])
flatten_arr = arr.flatten()
print(flatten_arr)

# output
# [0.         1.         1.41421356 2.        ]
```